# How to write an authentication rule to verify captcha on Google Firebase

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-security

I want to make a simple Form to collect user emails on my website deployed on Firebase.
I want to prevent bots thus I enabled an 'App Check' with ReCaptchaV3.
User must be able to post only one submission and since my website doesn't have registration I implemented an anonymous authentication so that ID is automatically set for each user.

How do I check that user is authenticated and captcha is passed in Firestore rules?

Here is code for a function to write a submission

```js
export const writeUserData = async (email) => {
    const db = getFirestore();
    const uid = auth.currentUser?.uid
    const docRef = await addDoc(collection(db, `newsletter/${uid}/entries`), {
        email: email
    });
    console.log(docRef);
}
```

Here is Firestore ruleset

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
    match /databases/{database}/documents {
        allow read: if false;

        match /newsletter/{userId}/entries {
          allow write: if request.auth != null;
        }
  }
}
```

What do I get:

> Uncaught (in promise) FirebaseError: Missing or insufficient permissions.

Comment: If you check `if (auth.currentUser != null)` right before calling to Firestore?

Comment: Please add some logging so we can see the value of `uid` before you use it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I end up with the following rule set

```
rules_version = '2';

service cloud.firestore {
  match /databases/{database}/documents {
    match /newsletter/{userId}/entries/{document=**} {
        allow write: if request.auth != null && request.auth.uid == userId;
      }
  }
}
```

It works only if I add `{document=**}` to the collection I want edit